# Is there a way to use the Lyft app to authenticate a user?

Tags: lyft-api

When using user-specific endpoints from the Lyft API, we are required to obtain a bearer token using the 3-Legged authentication flow.

When using the API on a mobile device, is there a way to redirect the user to the Lyft app (if it's installed) to trigger the authentication flow instead of redirecting them to the `authorize` endpoint?

In this scenario, if the user is already logged in to their Lyft app, they wouldn't need to log in again, making it easier for them to complete the authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Lyft currently (12-12-2018) does not support single sign on (aka SSO):
https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication

You can use an embedded WebView on mobile, we were able to quickly implement this with AppAuth on both iOS and Android.